# How to get a connection between Google Cloud Run and Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, jdbc, google-cloud-sql, unix-socket

What I have: A Java11 Spring Boot application (embedded tomcat 9) with Hikari Pool (Grails 4) in a Docker Container based on eclipse-temurin:11-jre.
What I need: My application needs a connection to a mysql database, I want to use google cloud sql mysql database.
What my problem is: My application cannot establish a connection to the database when deployed to Google Cloud Run.

The base assumption that by defining Cloud SQL connections for my cloud run revision it magically adds a unix socket to my docker container disturbs me though as it's the only thing I don't understand.

Has anyone an idea on what to try or what to do? Maybe an explanation on how the socket connection is being created?
My next and last try would be to add cloud-sql-proxy plus iam credentials to my docker container but this seems to be against everything being recommended by the documentation. There must be something I oversee.

I followed the guide (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run) and red everything I could get my hands on.
What I understand from the docs is that somehow Google Cloud Run injects a unixsocket `/cloudsql/PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID` to my container to provide connection to the cloudsql database and I can access that socket using `jdbc:mysql:///DB_NAME?unixSocketPath=/cloudsql/PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID`.
I also tried defining `socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory` plus adding the `mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8` dependency and setting `cloudSqlInstance=PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID` and `ipTypes=PUBLIC`.

Comment: Is your database public (with public IP)?

Comment: The database is public and has a public IP, I can connect to it with sql proxy from my machine. From documentation I have assumed the socket injects sql proxy into my docker container.

Comment: Can you share you code to let us reproduce your issue?

Comment: Well kindoff. I cannot share the repository but I set up a separate grails4 app with similar dependencies: https://github.com/leonheyna/debug-doc
My core question though is how the unixSocket is being made available to my docker container or if I have to do anything for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasource properties seem not to work with grails 4 Connection Pool Config. I had to add all the necessary info like socket, cloudSqlInstance and unixSocketPath in the right order to the jdbc-url and things just work.

```
jdbc:mysql:///${DBNAME}?unixSocketPath=/cloudsql/${CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE}&cloudSqlInstance=${CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
```

did the trick for me. Having the socketFactory or cloudSqlInstance parameter first did not work. Don't know why, but this solves my issue.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you set up the Datasource properties? It should work if you follow the instructions at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc.md.

Also the order of the parameters in the jdbc-url should not matter.

Comment: It was a problem with grails, not google. In grails you "just" configure datasource in an application.yaml and for that you can define as many datasource.properties.xyz as you want, it should build it into the jdbc url. As I removed the properties from that application.yaml and added them to the jdbc url manually things kept not working. Only after using the order I posted things worked.